# Is a compare between PHP and NodeJS worth?

Tags: php, node.js, compare

I start this topic saying that I use PHP since 2014 and I'm experienced with it, but recently (yesterday) I started to give a look to NodeJS.
Node is growing fast and it's been used by a lot of web-services.
I started using it yesterday,  but I found it less "beginner-user friendly" than PHP.
I'm not saying this as a beginner in computer programming, but as a Node-beginner.

What is your opinion?
Is it worth knowing both languages?

Comment: In my opinion.. it is always worth knowing a bit more about another language, and I often find it will give you ideas to use in other languages (if that makes sense) so I say yes, learn both!

Comment: But I wouldn't compare them!

Comment: If you must compare them, compare PHP + Apache vs NodeJS.   Or PHP + nginx vs NodeJS.  NodeJS is also a webserver.

Comment: you may like this book: [Node.js for PHP Developers (by Daniel Howard)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026013.do)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah: That's not strictly true - you can write a web server  in Node with very little effort, but it doesn't come with one out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it worth knowing both languages ?

If you come from php development, learning node is a great idea. 
It ll teach you in a soft way the concurrent programming pattern, and also event/stream programming,
it will lead you to face problems regarding the underlying OS in a soft way.

All sort of stuff that PHP greatly solves for you right out of the box and which you never think about.

Node will also give you the impression of a bigger playground to explore.

But, if you want to be productive when it s about building website, i believe PHP is better.
On the other hand, if you are looking for performance, node **may** be better, but true performance comes with compiled languages like GO, not scripted languages.

Finally, if php was not plumbed by all those damn heavy javaesque framework, it would be a really nice environment with a good trade off between speed and complexity.
Node gives you speed, but it comes with a price about the complexity which can be very costly.

Comment: Man, you are totally right. I'm starting Node and I find it really difficult to understand and use.

Comment: At the time i was switching from php to node, i found this complexity was lovely and motivating, today i think it was a very good thing to do, it gave me good skills to switch to lower programming languages like GO. Happy learning !

Comment: Node alone is not suitable for web development as it's complex. The default choice of most of the developers is expressjs, but you can use PHP alone to develop any big website.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner of both language i noted the following advantages of both languages

**PHP**

- Mixing code with content
- Deep code base
- No client app needed
- SQL
- Speed of coding

**NodeJs**

- Separating concerns
- Newer code means more modern features
- Service calls are thinner than HTML-fat PHP calls
- JSON
- Raw speed

You can read full article [Here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2866712/php/php-vs-node-js-an-epic-battle-for-developer-mind-share.html)

Comment: I noticed that NodeJS code style is more low-level than PHP one. Can that be the problem I'm experiencing with NodeJS?

Comment: Because when I started with PHP i found it very understandable. Same thing didn't happen with Node

Comment: `Mixing code with content` Just because it's possible, doesn't mean you should do it; I find it difficult to consider this as an advantage

Comment: php is more user friendly as compared to nodejs

Comment: `Service calls are thinner than HTML-fat PHP calls` PHP doesn't legally oblige to provide HTML-fat responses, or even HTML responses at all; just because many people do so, doen't mean that it's a legal requirement to do so.... haven't you heard of json or xml?

Comment: `Newer code means more modern features` You do realise that PHP has had several major releases over the last 20 years, the last in November 2015.... how new do you want?

Comment: @ Mark Baker i am beginner what do you realize which is bitter to learn